# Difference between passing function and the () => {} in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

What is the difference between these two? Only (1) is working and (2) is stuck in the browser;

(1) `app.get('/source*', createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider}))`

(2) `app.get('/source*', () => {
  createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider})
})`

Comment: In the first you are executing the function createProxyMiddleware, in the second, you are passing a function that will execute the function createProxyMiddleware, the second is called High Order Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider})
```

this returns a function that is yet to be excuted with the parameters from express middleware.
to make second example to work, you will simply need to excute the returned function as following

```js
2) app.get('/source*', (req, res, next) => {
  const func = createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider});
  func(req, res, next);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

in option (2) you placed `createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider})` INSIDE a function that doesn't handle the request nor returns a method that does.

`() => {}` is a shorthand for writing :

function()  {}

so in essence, the code in option (2) is the same as  :

```
app.get('/source*', function () {
  createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider})
});
```

and basically your own function took over as the renderer.

I haven't tried it yet, but consider trying to return `createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider})` from your function.

Example:

```
app.get('/source*',  () =>  {
  // do here whatever you planned on doing inside your function before returning the renderer 

  return createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```js
app.get('/source*', (req,res,next) => {
  try {
    createProxyMiddleware({ target: serviceProvider})
  }
  catch(error) {
    next(error)
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That second argument for get needs to match argument signature  (request, response, next), which is the signature for any middleware in express, including an endpoint controller. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

1 creates a standard middleware function that is correct.

2 doesnt return anything, doesn't return anything on the response, and doesn't  call "next()" to move onto the next request middleware.

Hope that helps. I'm answering from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for a second that the `createProxyMiddelware` function returns the value "hello". Then we could re-write your two scnearios like this:

```
1. app.get('/source*', "hello")
2. app.get('/source*', () => "hello")
```

So you can see the difference now. In the first scenario, you are evaluating the `createProxyMiddleware` function. In the second case, the second argument is a callback function, which, when invoked, will call the `createProxyMiddelware` function